# JavaScript Space After Function

Tags: javascript, function, coding-style, whitespace

I know that white space is irrelevant in JavaScript, but I am curious about style.

When defining a function like:

```
function Foo(a, b, c) {}
```

I do not put a space after the function name. But, if I am creating a function as an expression:

```
Bar(function (a, b, c) {
    // do something
})
```

or

```
{
    Foo: function (a, b, c) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I find myself naturally typing a space. I think this is because I've trained myself to type a space immediately after the function keyword (or keywords in general). However, depending on the context, space can look awkward. What makes more sense? what do most people do?

Sorry if this has been asked before; I didn't see it come up.

Comment: As you said, it's irrelevant, and not really constructive. It's just a matter of choice! This sort of question isn't suited for StackOverflow as it will just start debates over personal preference.

Comment: All I care about: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: I just noticed that Sublime Text 3's default JS syntax highlighting only colors function arguments when there is a space between function and (...)

Comment: Why was this closed as "not constructive" when [Space after function name is wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765942/space-after-function-name-is-wrong) is open?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do the same.

```
function () { ... }
function name() { ... }
```

It makes more sense to me this way. It is more readable with the space after the `function` keyword (I do the same with `if`, `while`, etc) and it makes sense not to put it after the function name since you usually invoke it without a space.

Comment: Only because my personal preference seems to echo your remark: I put a space after the function name when I define it and no space when I invoke it so I can immediately spot what the `function` keyword is used for when I see one (for some reason, I find this can be a matter of confusion for a few ms).

Comment: Better answer at [Space after function name is wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765942/space-after-function-name-is-wrong)

Answer (score 5):

It is matter of personal preference. No doubt proper spacing does aid to readability which is always a good idea.

The important thing though when it comes to *JavaScript coding style*, is to always put starting curly brace on the same (due to [automatic semi-colon insertion](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/6/automatic-semicolon-insertion/)) line unlike:

```
function myFunc() 
{
    return
    {
        name: 'Jane'
    };
}

var f = myFunc();
console.log(f); // undefined
```

---

**Read More:**

- [Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, when coding Javascript i want my code to be as readable as possible and I've gotten to find that having a whitespace to separate the the keyword ease the reading, for me.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

If the `()` is the function invocation operator, *don't* put a space before it. In all other cases *do* put a space before it.

```
function f ( x ) {
    // ...
}

var g = function ( y ) {
    // ...
};

f( 1 );
g( 2 );
```

That way, you can identify invocation operators more easily.

Comment: I find this really unreadable. There is rather *too much* whitespace. I would definitely leave out the spacing after `(` and before `)`.