# Space after function name is wrong?

Tags: javascript

I was using JSLint and I got an error for putting a space after the function name. Why is that bad?

```
function coolness () {
    var hi = "this";
}
```

ERROR: Problem at line 1 character 19: Unexpected space between 'coolness' and '('.

Comment: It is bad because a certain crotchety senior citizen was in a bad mood when he wrote jslint, as you will constantly be if you continue to use it.

Comment: Conventions help keeping code more readable. Consistency across many such functions is essential.

Comment: See Crockford's talk https://youtu.be/taaEzHI9xyY?t=1949

Answer (score 49, accepted):

JSLint is not a JavaScript syntax checker as much as it is a JavaScript style checker. The style guidelines it uses are those written by Douglas Crockford.

Some people do not agree with his style decisions, some people do. They are not law and you are not required to follow them. Alternative JS linters such as [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) exist.

The particular rule you are running into is [here](https://www.crockford.com/code.html#function):

> There should be no space between the name of a function and the (left parenthesis) of its parameter list.

JavaScript is not whitespace-sensitive. You can add this space if it makes you feel better. (It is not standard, however.)

Comment: This is way better than the other answers that are just "follow the style guidelines this website made up". It actually answers the question! Who would've thought!

Answer (score 60):

[According to Crockford](http://crockford.com/javascript/code.html#function),

For *named* functions, DO NOT insert space between **function name** and parentheses:

```
function doStuff() {
  //stuff here
}
```

For *anonymous* functions, DO insert space between `function` keyword and parentheses:

```
function () {
  //stuff here
}
```

Comment: IMHO (and Crockford's) this makes the two kinds of function easier to distinguish. I think sticking to Crockford's rules even where you wouldn't naturally is a good idea because they are consistent and validatable using JSLint. They are the de-facto code style rule for Javascript. Unless you have a really good reason to use something different, I wouldn't. (And not agreeing with Crockford because you've always coded another way is not a really good reason)

Comment: @rjmunro +1 - for the comment. Its currently the only place on the page that 'explains WHY it is bad' (without simply dogmatically repeating the rules of the convention).

Comment: I can tell the two apart. Is adding a special case style rule worth it? I don't think so, FWIW, the d3.js library breaks Crockford's suggestion, which is fine by me.

Comment: Crockford's rationale: "If the space is omited, then it can appear that the function's name is function, which is an incorrect reading." I find this unpersuasive. Does this bother anyone? Does it cause bugs?

Comment: @DavidJames I find it to be more of an issue with consistency.  If you put a space after "if" and "for" and "while," you should put a space after "function."

Comment: It's not that hard. Put a space after function keyword. period.

Comment: How would one ever run the second "anonymous" function? If it's not an IIFE nor named?

Answer (score 12):

Please check the javascript code convetions bellow and you will find your answer.

> http://crockford.com/javascript/code.html#function
>
> There should be no space between the name of a function and the ( (left parenthesis) of its parameter list. There should be one space between the ) (right parenthesis) and the { (left curly brace) that begins the statement body. The body itself is indented four spaces. The } (right curly brace) is aligned with the line containing the beginning of the declaration of the function.

**Example for a *function*:**

```
function outer(c, d) {
    var e = c * d;

    function inner(a, b) {
        return (e * a) + b;
    }

    return inner(0, 1);
 }
```

**Example for *anonymous function*:**

```
div.onclick = function (e) {
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, your code is perfectly valid, although some code style standards dictate that there should not be such space (for example, the one that @Bodgan cited).

In fact, when you compress your code (using one of many tools like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)) these spaces are entirely removed - including the ones before/after curly brackets as cited by @Bodgan. And it's valid JS of course.

Answer (score -1):

I think if your project want to have only one style (`function name () {...}` VS `function name() {...}`), the former is worse because:

1. Many conventional coding style guidelines have no space between function name and left parenthesis in a function declaration. (That mean, doing the opposite is introducing divisions)

E.g.

C++:

```
void main() {
}
```

PHP:

```
function run() {
}
```

2. I think function call and function declaration is not worthy enough to need two different styles (#1). It's not following the KISS principle.

   For example: In few occasions, I copy a function declaration template because the function have many parameters (there may be no good auto-completion hint), and paste it into a code position to turn it into a function call. If two styles there, I will need additional care (assume no linter) to remove the extra space in-between `functionName (longParameterList...)`.

Remarks:

#1 - some opinions argue for easier searching in files for function declarations, which I don't think a persuasive-enough reason to add the extra style to remember in coding.

Comment: I'm aware that standardjs.com promote the style the OP suggested. I'm not used to writing like that actually. Maybe I must always need a re-formatter to add the extra space for me on save, if the project need to conform to that. :P