# Why is my function with parameter not working

Tags: javascript

I am new to java script. And i am trying to pass a parameter to function. But the onclick event not working:

My Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

    <script src="t.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Next step" onclick="symbol_won(X)" />
    </body>
 </html>
```

My js file is:

```
function symbol_won (symbol)
{ 
    alert("gr");
}
```

Comment: Because `X` is not defined. If you meant to pass the string `'X'`, you need quotes.

Comment: add quotes
... onclick="symbol_won('X')"...
or define variable X
var X = 'hello';

Comment: `function symbol_won(symbol)` - without space before the clamp

Comment: @aldanux That has absolutely no effect

Comment: @Ian - I know but: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9765980/2097224

Comment: Is the js file even loading? Try adding a simple `alert('load-start');` to the top of the t.js file. Then add `alert('load-end');` to the end of the file.

Comment: @aldanux I agree that the space "shouldn't" be there. But it would've been more constructive if you explained that in your original comment (and this could've been avoided), instead of making it seem like it was required to leave that space out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have not defined `x` variable.

Define the variable X like:-

```
var X = 'Variable';
```

Also put quotes while passing it.

```
 onclick="symbol_won(X)"
```

Comment: Those are two different answers: You need *either* a variable `X` *or* quotes (to pass a string), not both.

Answer (score 2):

Your proper input-element code should be:

```
<input type="button" value="Next step" onclick="symbol_won('X')"
```

where `'X'` is a string surrounded by **single-quotes** *so you don't break the HTML attribute*