# Can you write anonymous functions in javascript like this: "function () {}"?

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

I know you can write anonymous functions like this:

```
function() {
  ...
}
```

But can you also separate the "function" keyword and the parameters?

```
function () {
  ...
}
```

Does it make any difference?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Did you *try* it before asking here?

Comment: just your preference....

Comment: No. Now I have to fill...

Comment: I tried it before, and it didn't change anything, but I wasn't sure :)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Space after function name is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765942/11683), [JavaScript Space After Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9300636/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space after function name is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765942/space-after-function-name-is-wrong)

Comment: That one semicolon ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both the way you write it is valid and will work.
It's about dev, if you prefer to have the brackets with a space - or not - with the keyword function

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid and correct, but if someone is using the linter then linter may generate the error based on rule configured.